# How can you reference a Windows Store app library in Linqpad?

Tags: linqpad, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 8.1 (Universal Windows Store App) library that is installed into Visual Studio 2013 via a Visual Studio Extension. Once installed, I see it in Add Reference -> Windows -> Extensions -> MyLibrary for Windows Store Apps. I would like to be able to do some testing of this code in Linqpad. Is it possible to reference this library?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://superuser.com/questions/463360/where-are-apps-from-the-windows-store-installed-to

Comment: Unfortunately no but appreciate the response. I'm looking to tinker with a Windows Store App API that as far as I can tell, is only accessible through VS.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me: 
**Query Properties** - **Additional References** - **Browse** to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd`. Then if you have registered, Namespaces will prompt to be added.